# Read all widget from external module in tkinter

Tags: python, python-3.x, tkinter, ttk, customtkinter

I want create online application with tkinter that widgets and menus and ... ,read from one .py file

I made a program with tkinter that after the user enters his username and password according to the access level, he will create all the widgets from an external module. It means that after opening the program every time, a file is downloaded in the user's system and all the widgets and menus are created from that file. Is this way possible?

Comment: Yes, it's possible. Tkinter and python can easily read data from a remote serve and then process it as if it was code.

Comment: the question needs sufficient code for a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)

Comment: I wonder why you don't deploy the .py file alongside with the program script from the first place.